# Skip list not inserting elements in higher levels

Tags: c, skip-lists

I'm having problem with insert in skip list.
When I'm inserting elements to the skip list it only adding the elements to the lower level, not to the higher levels.
When I'm trying to go to the down levels it explode.
appreciate your help.
thank you.

```
#ifndef _SkipList_
#define _SkipList_

// a value not supposed in stack and queue
#define     EMPTY   0x7FFFFFFF

// new types
typedef int DATA;                   // a type for data (easy to change)
typedef enum {False, True} BOOL;    // a boolean type

// Node
typedef struct node 
{
    DATA            key;
    struct node*    next;
    struct node*    down;

}NODE;

typedef struct 
{
    NODE *head;
}SkipList;

#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "SkipList.h"

BOOL SL_init(SkipList *list)
{
    if (!list)
        return False;
    NODE *temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    temp->down = NULL;
    temp->key = INT_MIN;
    temp->next->key = INT_MAX;
    list->head = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    list->head = temp;

    NODE *start, *end;
    start = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    end = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    start->key = INT_MIN;
    start->down = NULL;
    end->down = NULL;
    end->key = INT_MAX;
    list->head = start;
    list->head->next = end;
    return True;

}

NODE* SL_find(SkipList *list, DATA Value)
{
    NODE *p = list->head;
    while(1)
    {
        for(;p->next->key <= Value; p = p->next);
        if(p->down == NULL)
            break;
        p = p->down;
    }
    if(p->key==Value)
        return p;
    else 
        return NULL;
}
NODE* new_node(DATA x, NODE *n, NODE *d){
    NODE *p;
    p = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p->key = x;
    p->next = n;
    p->down = d;
    return p;
}
BOOL toss()
{
    int random = rand() % 2;
    printf(" %d\n", random);
    if (random == 0){
        return False;
    }
    return True;
}

NODE *SkipList_addAfter(NODE*p, DATA Value)
{
    NODE *temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (temp)
    {
        temp->key = Value;
        temp->next = p->next;
        temp->down = p->next->down;
        p->next = temp;
    }
    return temp;
}



NODE* insert2(NODE *old_lst, DATA x){
    NODE *deeper, *newnode;
    for (; old_lst->next->key <= x ; old_lst = old_lst->next);
    NODE *temp ;
    if (old_lst->down == NULL){
        temp = SkipList_addAfter(old_lst, x);
        return temp;
    }
    deeper = insert2(old_lst->down, x);
    if (deeper == NULL || toss())
        return NULL;
    else{
        newnode = SkipList_addAfter(old_lst, x);
        newnode->down = deeper;
    }
    return newnode;

}
NODE* insert1(NODE *lst, DATA x){
    NODE *deeper;
    deeper = insert2(lst,x);
    if (deeper == NULL || toss())
        return lst;
    return new_node(INT_MIN, INT_MAX, lst);
}


NODE* insert(SkipList *list, DATA x){
    if (SL_find(list, x))
        return NULL;    
    return insert1(list->head, x);
}
void print(SkipList *list){
    NODE *temp = list->head->next;
//  while (!temp->down){
        for (; temp->key <INT_MAX; temp = temp->next){
            printf("->%d\n", temp->key);
//      }
//      temp = temp->down;
//      printf("\n\n");
    }
}
void deleteD(NODE *node)
{
    NODE* tmp;

    if (!node || !(tmp = node->next)) 
        return False;


    node->next = tmp->next;
    free(tmp);
    return True;

}
BOOL SL_Delete(SkipList *list, DATA x)
{
    NODE *p = SL_find(list, x);
    if (p == NULL)
        return False;
    NODE *temp = list->head;
    for (; temp->next->key < p->key; temp = temp->next);
    while (temp->down != NULL){
        deleteD(temp);
        temp = temp->down;
    }
    deleteD(temp);
    return True;

}
void main(){
    SkipList *list = (SkipList*)malloc(sizeof(SkipList));
    SL_init(list);

    int arr[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,5};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        insert(list, arr[i]);
    }
    /*
    if (!SL_Delete(list, 7))
        printf("cant delete");
        */
    print(list);
//  SL_Delete(list, 4);
//  print(list);
//  if (SL_find(list, 7))
//      printf("\nfound");

}
```

Comment: Someone ? please help:)

Comment: in SL_find() `for(;p->next->key <= Value; p = p->next);` should *probably* be `for(;p->key <= Value; p = p->next);`

Comment: Not an answer, but note that names that start with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation to use, which means you should not use those names in your own code.  I suggest `#ifndef SKIPLIST_H_INCLUDED` etc as a workable unambiguous name to test and define.  Or use some UUID for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this is problem. I think the problem is in the init function or at  the insert function.